# What does Kikuhiko mean by saying "what I did to your daughter" to Sukeroku?

Tags: descending-stories

I noticed that at the end of Season 1, Kikuhiko is at the grave of Sukeroku and he says something on the lines of "are you mad because of what I did to your daughter?"

What does he mean? What did he do to say that?

> Did he impregnate Sukeroku's daughter and is he making reference to that?